# Search / Filter State NGXS

Tags: angular, search, filtering, ngxs

I am new to NGXS and trying to integrate it into a small project. The only problem is that there are no good examples of a search / filter on state.

My app gets a list of products from a backend API. It shows them by SKU on the page. I want the user to be able to type in an SKU in the input field and have the list automatically filter products as the user types.

products.state.ts:

```
@Selector()
static getProductList(state: ProductStateModel) {
  return state.products;
}

@Selector()
static prodFilter(searchObj: any[]) {
  // something needs to happen here in order to filter state
}
```

products.component.ts:

```
@Select(ProductState.getProductList) products: Observable<Product[]>;

filterForm = this.fb.group({ sku: null });

constructor( private store: Store, private fb: FormBuilder ) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.store.dispatch( new GetProducts() );
}

//something in here (ngOnInit? ngOnChanges?) to pass (cloned??) product state into selector??
```

products.component.html:

```
<form
  [formGroup]='filterForm'
  novalidate
  ngxsForm='products.filterForm'
  (ngSubmit)='onSubmit()'
>
  <input type='number' formControlName='sku' />
  <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>

<mat-accordion class='product-accordion'>
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor='let product of products | async'>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      SKU: {{ product.sku }}
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <p>${{ product.price }}</p>
    <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

I have so many questions. I believe that I shouldn't be mutating the products state directly so would I clone it? Would the HTML output change then? Should I create a new state.ts file for the filtered products?

Any help would be much appreciated (especially a stackblitz example)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might find this easier if you model your state like this, capturing the base products list and the text entered in the search textbox:

```
export interface ProductsStateModel {
  products: Product[];
  filterText: string; // Your SKU value that is entered
}
```

.. Then in your state, use a selector to project out the filtered list that you actually want to display on the UI (`filteredProducts`).

```
@State<ProductsStateModel>({
 name: 'products'
})
export class ProductsState { 

   @Selector()
   static filteredProducts(state: ProductsStateModel) { 
      return state.products.filter(p => p.sku === state.filterText);
   }

   @Action(ProductSkuEntered)
   updateFilter({patchState}: StateContext<ProductStateModel>, {payload}: ProductSkuEntered) {
       patchState({ filterText: payload.skuText });
   }
..

}
```

In the UI, you can in your template then subscribe to the selector i.e. in `products.component.ts` use `@Select(ProductsState.filteredProducts) products$`.

When the search text changes, you can dispatch an action to the store to update that string in the state i.e. `store.dispatch(new ProductSkuEntered({ skuText: enteredText }));`
The NGXS selector will then automatically update your 'filteredProducts` list to display just those that match the text.

It's also nice to hook up a `debounceTime` to the change in the text so that you only filter when the user has stopped typing. i.e. only dispatch the `ProductSkuEntered` after the debounce.

Note: I see you are using the NGXS forms plugin - I don't have experience with that plugin but it is not required for this scenario (although you might be using it elsewhere).