# Searching Data From Different Component in Angular NGXS

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, state-management, ngxs, angular-state-managmement

I'm trying to figure out how will i able to search in NGXS from different component. I have my searchbar from the navbar component while i'm displaying my data from app component which is a different component.
Please see this stackblitz link
[CLICK HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngxs-searching-different-component?file=src/app/navbar/navbar.component.html)

> CODE

```
this.peopleForm.get('name').valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(500)).subscribe(
  (name: string) => {
    console.log(name);
    this.people$ = this.store.select(AppState.nameFilter(name));
  }
)
```

Comment: just one question.. why you have not use `output`???

Comment: @programoholic. What if navbar is on a different module? Output works only on parent child

Comment: Keep an eye on unsubscribing. For me it seems you're creating a lot of subscriptions to the store without unsubscribing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a look at your StackBlitz, it seems you are trying to filter a list based on what is entered in the `peopleForm` input element.

Rather than tryring to select from the store when this value changes in the component, I've found a good way to model this problem is to store the 'search text' in the state, and use a `@Selector` that applies the current search value to the list returns those items that meet the criteria.

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55753415/search-filter-state-ngxs) where I've outlined this approach.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. Your answer i believe works if you are on the same component right? Mine if the search is on a different component from where the output is displayed. Can your forked my stackblitz? Thanks

Comment: It won't matter what combination of components you have - in your case the navbar component would dispatch the action to the state.  Then app component will see the filtered list be virtue of subscribing to Selector

Comment: Can you forked my stackblitz if its ok with you?  Thank you

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngxs-searching-different-component-erexd2